# Forgot Android Password

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, recovery-mode, password, locked-out

I've tried waiting for the reset via google account to show up, but it didn't. I've tried to use [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager?u=0), but when I try to reset the password, it says "Since Google has verified that a screen lock is already set, the password you entered won't be needed." and nothing happens to my phone.

This is with Android 5.0 lollipop.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! For some first-aid and hints, please also see our [locked-out tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google removed the option to reset your password using your Google credentials or Android Device Manager in Android Lollipop. If you're rooted, you may be able to remove or reset your password using adb but this seems very hit and miss and the methods vary. Apart from that, a factory reset from recovery is your only option.

Answer (score -1):

Is your Android version 4.4 or below? If it is, a button should appear below the lock screen pattern to unlock your phone using your Google password.

If it isn't, you should be able to use Android Device Manager in your browser and (using the "lock" button) create a temporary password for your phone (I have tried this and it works).